# The sum of squares of $x^8-x+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> I want to find the sum of squares of $x^8-x+1$.

Attempts. $$(x^2-x+1)(x^6+x^5-x^3-x^2+1)$$ so $$x^2-x+1=\bigg(x-\frac {1}{2}\bigg)^2+\frac {3}{4}$$

My further progress.

\begin{aligned}x^6+x^5-x^3-x^2+1=x^5(x+1)-x^2(x+1)+1=(x^5-x^2)(x+1)+1=x^2(x^3-1)(x+1)+1=x^2(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)+1=x^2(x^2-1)(x^2+x+1)+1\end{aligned}

I can't go further anymore. The more traditional and easy way, answers that get the sum of squares without being random, are more preferable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually , the number of real roots is determined with the sturm chains (after having established bounds for the roots). Finding the sum of squares will in general not be easier I think (if this works in general at all). Here there might be better ways.

Comment: Do you want the sum of the squares of the *roots* or of the polynomial itself?  They are very different.  One matches your title, the other matches the answers you have.

Comment: "*I just want to do this with sum of squares representation*" $\;-\;$ Why? It's a lot easier to prove it directly. A real root must necessarily be positive, and if $x \ge 1$ then $x^8 \ge x$ so $p(x) \ge 1$, else if $0 \lt x \lt 1$ then $x^8-x \gt -1$ so $p(x) \gt 0$.

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks. I think now I understand what is requested :-)

Answer (score 5):

To construct another possible decomposition of *the sum of squares*, we can directly apply the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) : $( n=4 )$

$$
\begin{align}x^8+\frac {1}{16}+\frac {1}{16}+\frac {1}{16}&≥4\sqrt [4]{\frac {x^8}{16^3}}\\
&=\frac 12x^2\end{align}
$$

Thus, we can rewrite the original polynomial as follows :

$$
\begin{align}x^8-x+1=\left(x^8-\frac 12 x^2+\frac {3}{16}\right)+\left(\frac 12x^2-x+\frac{13}{16}\right)\end{align}
$$

Let's recall the following formula/identity :

$$
\small {\begin{align} \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace &a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4-4abcd\\
=\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace &\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2+\left(c^2-d^2\right)^2+2(ab-cd)^2\end{align}}
$$

---

Thus, applying the above formula *the sum of squares* is ready to be constructed :

$$
\begin{align}x^8-x+1=\frac {1}{16}\left(4x^4-1\right)^2+\frac 18\left(2x^2-1\right)^2+\frac 12(x-1)^2+\frac {5}{16}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$x^8 - x + 1 = (x^4-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 + (x^2-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 + (x-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 + \tfrac{1}{4}$$

Comment: I feel, and I'm sure OP does too, that it would be better if you explained how you got to this conclusion.

Comment: In my opinion it's the best answer here. It's really clear, how we can get this solution. +1.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I like this answer  but if $x^{88}-x+1=...^2+...^2$  so in my opinion it is really clear again

Comment: @Hellomath  can you do $x^{16} - x +\frac{5}{4}  \; \; ? \; \; $  And $ \; x^{32} - x +\frac{3}{2}  \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: @WillJagy see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm)

Comment: @Hellomath Hint for $\,x^4 - x + \frac{3}{4}\,$: complete the two squares in $\,\underbrace{x^4 \color{red}{- x^2}} \color{red}{+} \underbrace{\color{red}{x^2} - x} + \frac{3}{4}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv What is the method here? 1) Can't we use $1/4$ instead of $1/2$ in this answer? 2) Next answer suddenly discovered $1/16$ and used amgm inequality. What does inequality have to do with it? 3) Next answer is using derivative, not actually what I'm looking for.  I couldn't find good answers to these questions.

Comment: @Hellomath 1) Have you tried it? If you use $1/4$ instead of $1/2$ the terms don't cancel out, and the RHS is no longer equal to the LHS. The point of the terms in red shown in my comment is that they cancel out, and allow you to isolate a sum of two squares. The same idea works in the answer here to get a sum of three squares for your polynomial. 2) That's an entirely different approach, and AM-GM is only used to justify the following steps. If you guessed the expression on the last line somehow, you don't need AM-GM at all. 3) It's not entirely clear why you are looking for a sum of squares.

Comment: @dxiv Ahh, I completely agree with your comment . Indeed, using AM-GM inequality was nonsense here . Because, it is enough to note that the formula $$\begin{align} \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace &a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4-4abcd\\
=\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace &\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2+\left(c^2-d^2\right)^2+2(ab-cd)^2\end{align}$$  Do you think, should I delete this step from my answer ? or it seems something ok ? Good to see your comment .

Comment: @lonestudent AM-GM justifies the idea of breaking out the $x^2 / 2$ and $3/16$ terms, so I'd leave it there. If anything, I would add a line in the last step explaining precisely how the identity is used to transform the first parenthesis into a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 2):

We will find a sum of squares representation of $\,x^8-x+1\,$ by using the abscissa $\,x_{\mathrm{min}}\,$ of the absolute minimum point of the function $\,f(x)=x^8-x+1:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\,.$

Since
$f’(x)=8x^7-1<0\;\;\;$ for any $\;x<\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}\;\;,$
$f’(x)=8x^7-1=0\;\;\;$ for $\;x=\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}\;\;,$
$f’(x)=8x^7-1>0\;\;\;$ for any $\;x>\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}\;\;,$

the abscissa of the absolute minimum point of the function $\,f(x)=x^8-x+1:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\,$ is $\,x_{\mathrm{min}}=\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}\,.$

Now, we will write a sum of squares representation of $\,x^8-x+1\,$ by using the abscissa $\,x_{\mathrm{min}}\,:$

$x^8-x+1=$

$=\left(x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2+2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-x+1=$

$=\left(x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2+2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\left(x^2-x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\right)^2+4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6x^2-2x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-x+1=$

$=\left(x^4\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2\!+\!2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\left(x^2\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\right)^2\!+\!4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6x^2\!-\!3x_{\mathrm{min}}^8\!-\!x\!+\!1\!=$

$\require{cancel}=\left(x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2+2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\left(x^2-x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\right)^2+4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6\left(x-x_{\mathrm{min}}\right)^2+\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{8x_{\mathrm{min}}^7}}}-4x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-3x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{x}}}+1=$

$\!=\!\left(x^4\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\!\right)^2\!\!+\!2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\!\left(x^2\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\!\right)^2\!\!+\!4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6\left(x\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}\!\right)^2\!+\!1\!-\!7x_{\mathrm{min}}^8\!\!=$

$\!=\!\left(x^4\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\!\right)^2\!\!+\!2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\!\left(x^2\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\!\right)^2\!\!+\!4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6\!\left(x\!-\!x_{\mathrm{min}}\!\right)^2\!+\!1\!-\!\dfrac78x_{\mathrm{min}}\,.$

Since $\;1-\dfrac78x_{\mathrm{min}}=1-\dfrac78\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}>1-\dfrac78>0\;,\;$ we get the following representation of $\,x^8-x+1\,$ as a sum of squares :

$x^8-x+1=\left(x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2+2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\left(x^2-x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\right)^2+4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6\left(x-x_{\mathrm{min}}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac78x_{\mathrm{min}}}\,\right)^2.$

By using this representation, we can get the minimum value  of $\,x^8-x+1\,$ which is

$x_{\mathrm{min}}^8-x_{\mathrm{min}}+1=1-\dfrac78x_{\mathrm{min}}=1-\dfrac78\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}>0\,.$

Comment: @IraeVid, yes, you are right, OP is asking for a sum of squares representation and I found one which is $$x^8-x+1=\left(x^4-x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\right)^2+2x_{\mathrm{min}}^4\left(x^2-x_{\mathrm{min}}^2\right)^2+4x_{\mathrm{min}}^6\left(x-x_{\mathrm{min}}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac78x_{\mathrm{min}}}\,\right)^2.$$ where $\,x_{\mathrm{min}}=\sqrt[7]{\dfrac18}\,.$

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that. +1 Well explained!

Comment: @IraeVid, you are welcome.